# android how to change from if-else to switch case

Tags: android

I have an application about pmt function.  However there are so many conditions that need to be handled. Somehow the app will not work with having more than 12 if-else. I want to use switch case, but i still not really understand how to use switch case(been 1 and half month since my 1st try using eclipse).Any example will be highly appreciated.

here is my example code:

```
    if(String1.toString().equals("condition1")){
          //do something
          if(String2.toString().equals("condition1.1")&& String3.toString().equals("condition1.2")){
        //do something else
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
      if(String2.toString().equals("condition1.##")&& String3.toString().equals("condition1.##")){
        //do something else
    }
    }
else if(String1.toString().equals("condition2")){
          //do something
          if(String2.toString().equals("condition2.1")&& String3.toString().equals("condition2.2")){
        //do something else
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
      if(String2.toString().equals("condition2.##")&& String3.toString().equals("condition2.##")){
        //do something else
    }
    }
if(String1.toString().equals("condition3")){
          //do something
          if(String2.toString().equals("condition3.1")&& String3.toString().equals("condition3.2")){
        //do something else
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
      if(String2.toString().equals("condition3.##")&& String3.toString().equals("condition3.##")){
        //do something else
    }
    }
```

and still keep going....to handle all possibilities .I am wondering, How to do this in switch case . Or a better implementation if we have 3 times 3 conditions. For example a,b,c(suppose these three conditions can only be used once) and d,e,f and g,h,i then condition 1 is a,d,g ; condition 2 is a,d,h condition 3 is a,d,i ; condition 4 a,e,g........on so on

Note:Suppose that the API version is 8-11 (old android)

thanks

Comment: yes all are Strings, its like a string comparison but in large scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is dependent on your target version of android. From KitKat and upwards (API Level 19+), Java 7's `switch (String)` is available. I'd also strongly suggest trying to group the subcases (condition n.x) into different methods. It just gets very unwieldly quickly, otherwise:

```
switch (String1.toString) {
case "condition1":
    handleCase1(String2, String3);
    break;

case "condition2":
     handleCase2(String2, String3);
     break;
}
```

If that still results in too complex code, you can try a lookup table together with a *command pattern*:

```
class ConditionKey {
    final String String1;
    final String String2;
    final String String3;

    public int hashCode(); // hash strings
    public boolean equals(); // compare strings
}

interface ConditionCommand {
   // use whatever arguments the operation needs, you can also
   // add fields and initialize in the constructor
   void perform(final ConditionKey key, /* [...] */);
}

Map<ConditionKey, ConditionCommand> actionMap = new HashMap<>();
actionMap.put(
  new ConditionKey("condition1", "condition1.1", "condition1.2"),
  new ConditionCommand() {
      void perform(final ConditionKey key) {
         // perform  actions that need to be done
      }
  }
);
```

And then instead of the `if-else` or `switch-case`:

```
[...]
ConditionKey key = new ConditionKey(string1, string2, string3);
// get the action from the map
ConditionCommand command = actionMap.get(key);
// perform the command
command.perform(key);
```

Comment: I am targeting the SDK to  API 21 and minSDK API 8. Another question, what will happen if the user use a device with API lower than 19?

Comment: If you set `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19">` in `AndroidManifest.xml` your app will not install on devices with a lower version. If you don't, your application will crash, as it uses a feature that the virtual machine on the device does not provide.

Comment: what about BlackBelt answer? java 1.7 means java 7's , ins't it?

Comment: Java 1.7 is the colloquial term for Java 7. Java went from 1.4 to 5.0 to 6, to 7 to 8. In the true tradition of not catching up to marketing hype, a lot of people refer to Java 7 as Java 1.7, which it really is.

Comment: I am so sorry, i forget to mention that i want to make this works on a device with older version of API. I had to uncheck

Answer (score 1):

since java 1.7 switch on string is supported.

you could annidate two switch:

```
switch(String1) {
  case "condition1": {
      switch(String2) {
         case "condition1.1":
              break;
           // ... other cases
          default:
              break;
      }
  }
  break;
  // ... other cases
  default break;
}
```

Comment: yes it will. You have to compile  at least with version 19 of android sdk . If you are using android studio, eg `compileSdkVersion 19`
`buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"`

Comment: so, it requires API 19 on the device to be use-able?

Comment: no it does not. You have to compile with that version.

Comment: I am so sorry, i forget to mention that i want to make this works on a device with older version of API. I had to uncheck

Comment: It will work **also** on pre kitkat devices. Just write a demo and run it on an emulator with an old version of android